# Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a0 = [a0]

Tags: haskell

```
mymap f _ [] =  []
mymap f x (y:ys) =  f first y : mymap (f x ys)
    where if x /= [] first = head(x) else --there will not be else just playing around
```

All I wanna do is implement the built-in map but instead of one list, the f has 2 arguments (lists). When the ys becomes [], I want to create a new list, (by calling mymamp) but instead of x, I wanna use tail(x)==xs and go on that way till xs becomes []. And put all these lists to a final list. But I cant find an automatic/recursive way to do it.

Comment: Are you trying to do something similar to `zipWith`?

Comment: You have syntax error. `where` clause contains definitions, but you wrote an `if` expression here. You should really go through some Haskell tutorial, like http://learnyouahaskell.com/

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're calling `head(x)` without validating that `x` isn't empty - that's no a good idea. Instead, use pattern matching on `x` as well!

```
mymap f _ [] =  []
mymap f (x:xs) (y:ys) =  f x y : f x ys
-- add the other cases as well
```

Now, the error: notice that you're using `f` in to places:

1. `f first y` - here f is of type `a->b->c`
2. `f x ys` - here f is of type `[a]->[b]->c`

Haskell cannot infer `f`'s type, so it makes an educated guess and fails inferring another variable's type - hence the error.

The best advice in this case - add a type signature to `mymap`. Haskell is a smart language, in the majority of the cases it can manage just fine without your type signature - *if*, and that's one big *if*, you're code is valid. So always start with a type signature.

Comment: I don't think your code even parses now - `where` clauses are not defined like that. I'd really recommend the pattern matching approach.